# SKPaymentTransaction stuck

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I got a very annoying issue regarding in app purchases on iOS (consumable).

### Case

- I create a payment request
- I enter my credentials and confirm the
  purchase.
- I quit the app before the purchase is confirmed by Apple
- I then receive a popup from the springboard (app being killed) saying
  that payment was processed.

### Problem

When I launch my app again I add a transaction observer (all delegate method being implemented) doing:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
```

I log the pending transactions and their current state right after that:

```
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    /*
       Logging the content of[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue].transactions
       shows a transaction with a state of SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased
    */
```

But this transactions seems blocked since it never calls

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

The thing is that it might have been called the previous time but I crashed/quit before calling

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];`

Since `finishTransaction:` was never called for this transaction it's normal it's still pending but `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` should be called with this transaction right?

**Edit:** I get asked by iTunes for my password at every launch but giving the password or not does not change anything to the problem.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I wish. Nothing payment related is ever called after addTransactionObserver:

Comment: Try to remove the Observer on app start, `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];` after you run the app once remove the line again.  Whenever you add an transactionObserver , it is your duty to remove it. If you don’t, it will create some issues like apple account login screen may appear without any reason - See more at: http://innofied.com/in-app-purchase-working-ios-solution/#sthash.67bi8axU.sliOdcBW.dpuf

Comment: This is a temporary solution no? Whenever the user will crash or quit the app during the process the problem will remain.

Comment: No, as you can see on the page i referred to, you need to implement this line every time your transaction is done,  successful or not. You have to implement the `transaction failed` delegate method and handle the error yourself.

Comment: Here is another good tutorial that should help you: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: What bothers me with this answer is that you removeTransactionObserver at each callback so you're supposed to add an observer every time you make a purchase which does not seems like the way apple intend it to be used. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2387/_index.html I believe there is a better/cleaner way for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77913/discussion-between-user3817301-and-lovo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed.

I was using a remote notifications SDK and it was tracking purchases too (So I was able to send notifications to specific paying users). The SDK was adding a transactionObserver before the payment system and it wasn't doing anything with it. That means that the updateTransaction method was called but only the remote notif SDK was aware of this update.

After contacting the support they assured it was fixed in the latest SDK version and upgrading it did the trick.

Comment: Which SDK? I have the same issue!